# time remaining until charge is complete,iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am using :

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batLeft = [myDevice batteryLevel];
int i = [myDevice batteryState];    
int batinfo = batLeft * 100;
```

to find the battery status.
I am looking out to find, how to find the time remaining until the charge is complete.
ex: 1 hour 20 min remaining.
How can I find it programmatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't found any method for this in the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html), neither in the class-dumped, [private header](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UIDevice2.h) of the `UIDevice` class.

So we have to come up with something. The best "solution" I have in mind at the moment is similar to the approach taken when estimating download time: calculating an average speed of download/charging, and dividing the remaining amount (of data or charge) by that speed:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;
float prevBatteryLev = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel;
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(batteryCharged)
           name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification
         object:nil
];

- (void)batteryCharged
{
    float currBatteryLev = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel;
    // calculate speed of chargement
    float avgChgSpeed = (prevBatteryLev - currBatteryLev) / [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    // get how much the battery needs to be charged yet
    float remBatteryLev = 1.0 - currBatteryLev;
    // divide the two to obtain the remaining charge time
    NSTimeInterval remSeconds = remBatteryLev / avgChgSpeed;
    // convert/format `remSeconds' as appropriate
}
```

Comment: That assumes that charging is linear -- it isn't. Charging slows down dramatically as the battery gets close to full.

Comment: @duskwuff yes, and even the battery level reported by the OS may not be exact, etc. Why do you think I used the term **"average"** throughout? Shit happens...

Comment: Thanks H2CO3, i am not able to call batterCharge method.any suggestion

Comment: @iscavengers Why "are you not able" to call that method? Even more important: why would you need to call it? It's called by the notification center. You just do something in the end of the method with the obtained `remSeconds` value.

Comment: finally it worked. but on NSLog i am getting this :  remSeconds : -inf

Comment: @iscavengers that means `avgChgSpeed` was 0 for some reason. Time to fire up the debugger.

Comment: @iscavengers so how are you trying to use it?